# Retrofit 2 calling same request so many unwanted times in my app

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I have an android app already uploaded to store and working fine, sometimes when a lot of users open the app at the same time (eg. when sending a notification) our servers are getting overloaded and stops responding for about 10 to 15 minutes. I'm using Retrofit 2 to send requests to our server from the app, I've checked all the app requests there are no places where the request is happening when it shouldn't or needed, finally, I added a logging interceptor to retrofit to track the requests and I was surprised that each request is being called more than ten times for no apparent reason! as you can see in the following image:

[image: App requests log]

This is happening with all requests called from the app for no apparent reason. My service generator for Retrofit 2 is the following:

```
private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient
        = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS).addInterceptor(new FakeInterceptor())
        .addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor())
        .retryOnConnectionFailure(false);

private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer())
            .create();

private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL));



public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
```

I am sure request is only called once from my code but I have no idea why Retrofit is making all these useless and unnecessary requests. What might be the problem? Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: post the code that fires the request, retrofit is not going to execute a call unless you're probably triggered it somewhere

Comment: Side note, you should at jitter to your notifications so that you don't ddos your own servers...

Comment: @elmorabea I'm firing the request as usual, I define the client from createService as a global variable then I use client.enqueue to fire the request.

Comment: Maybe you are doing the enqueue call in a life cycle method, or something that is called repeatedly, post the code so we can help

Comment: @Shmuel I don't have a lot of users, basically, the notification is opened from 200 to 500 users at the same time but the amount of each user requests is huge as you can see. If I fix the problem of user huge request number I guess it will fix the problem with server overloading.

Comment: @elmorabea problem is this isn't happening with only one request, it's happening with all requests in the app and I already made sure they are not being called in any lifecycle method nor delegate nor interface nor callback nor broadcast hehe

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are creating multiple instances of the Retrofit client. You should declare a static instance of Retrofit in your class and change

`Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();`

to

`if(retrofit == null) {
  retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
}`

Reference: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1724